# Unable to set image width in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In my view controller, I added the following to be able to customize the NavigationBar, but when I got to setting the width and height of the logo, all I can change is the height.

When I edit the value in width - Nothing happens, even if I set it to 0.

Also, is it possible to use px instead of points?

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    // 1
    var nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    // 2
    nav?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
    nav?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    // 3
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
  // imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    // 4
    let image = UIImage(named: "trotterlogo.png")
    imageView.image = image
    // 5
    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
}
```

Comment: If you use `ScaleToFill` contentMode, it should change its width.

Comment: It didn't. Is there anyway to just use the original size as I uploaded this asset as an x1. but maybe that just doesn't matter.

Comment: Maybe you can try center mode.

Comment: And set imageView from to CGRectZero.

Comment: No modes changes the width.

Comment: What do you want to achieve, width? or keep the original size? I tested that ScaleToFill would change your imageView width to the width you specified in the frame. You can try some other images to test more.

Comment: I'd rather want to keep the original size

Comment: Ok - Solved - I had to add the image to the Universal x3!

Comment: What is Universal x3?

Comment: In the Images.xcassets you can add different image sizes depending on device

Comment: That explains it, are you testing it on iPhone 6 plus?

Comment: Sorry for late reply - No iPhone 6 "regular". lol